# Custom WCF Binding for Solace/JMS

Tags: .net, wcf, jms, solace

I'm going to use WCF over Solace messaging platform. AFAIK Solace is JMS-compatible, so JMS binding would also meet my purposes. I found [JNBridge](http://jnbridge.com/blog/deploying-net-jms-adapter-iis-part-1), but it's not free. So I'd like to know if there are any other solutions.

As a minimum I need to support topic publish/subscribe logic.

Ability to process various message properties like `CorrelationId` and `ApplicationMessageType` would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Solace does have a JMS API but another option for this case to is to use Solace's REST interface to initiate the WCF service.

More information on Solace's REST interface is available on the Solace Developer Portal:
http://docs.solace.com/Open-APIs-Protocols/REST-home.htm

Comment: That's a nice solution. System.Net.WebSockets seem to be even better if one needs a callback, can be they also used with Solace?